# LRU LinkedHashMap that limits size based on available memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, memory-management

I want to create a LinkedHashMap which will limit its size based on available memory (ie. when `freeMemory + (maxMemory - allocatedMemory)` gets below a certain threshold).  This will be used as a form of cache, probably using "least recently used" as a caching strategy.

My concern though is that allocatedMemory also includes (I assume) un-garbage collected data, and thus will over-estimate the amount of used memory.  I'm concerned about the unintended consequences this might have.

For example, the LinkedHashMap may keep deleting items because it thinks there isn't enough free memory, but the free memory doesn't increase because these deleted items aren't being garbage collected immediately.

Does anyone have any experience with this type of thing?  Is my concern warranted?  If so, can anyone suggest a good approach?

I should add that I also want to be able to "lock" the cache, basically saying "ok, from now on don't delete anything because of memory usage issues".

Comment: What is your application here?  It's hard to come up with a good answer without an idea of what the background intention is.  Is your HashMap a cache or what?

Comment: jprete, I've tried to clarify this - you are right, its a cache

Comment: This is a typical example of where GC and the java memory management shows its real messy face. It would be *so simple* to do such a thing in C++. Using GC, you cant execute commands like delete or free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm biased, but I really have to strongly recommend our [MapMaker](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) for this. Use the softKeys() or softValues() feature, depending on whether it's GC collection of the key or of the value that more aptly describes when an entry can be cleaned up.

Comment: I would like to use MapMaker (I make extensive use of Google Collections in my code), but is there any way to make it behave like an LRU cache which scales according to available memory?  Additionally, is there any way to "lock" it so that it will no-longer delete entries in response to garbage collection?

Comment: "behave like an LRU cache..."  -- that pretty much describes exactly what soft references will give you, yes.

"lock" it -- the only sensible answer to this involves copying the map: Map&lt;Key, Val&gt; strongCache = Maps.newHashMap(cache);

Comment: sorry about the &lt; garbage; there's no preview so I had to guess whether I would have to escape or not. :(

Comment: The danger of using soft/weak cache entries is that your cache algorithm suddenly becomes very dependent on (unpredictable) GC. Ideally what one would want is to have "hard" LRU logic for put/get/delete and soft/weak logic kicking in when cache memory goes over designated limit. Sadly, I can't imagine how this could be done. The only closest solution I can think of is a separate thread which does instrumentation and entry eviction, but that's just one massive hack.

Comment: Completely agree with @mindas. Simply relying on `SoftReference`s alone is terribly inefficient for caching. You're giving too much control to the GC. References deleted early equal extra work; references deleted late equal wasted memory.

Answer (score 0):

Caches tend to be problematic. IIRC, there's a `SoftCache` in Sun's JRE that has had many problems.

Anyway, the simplest thing is to use `SoftReference`s in the map. This should work fine so long as the overhead of `SoftReference` plus `Map.Entry` is significantly lower than the cached data.

Alternatively you can, like `WeakHashMap`, use a `ReferenceQueue` and either poll it or have a thread blocking on it (one thread per instance, unfortunately). Be careful with synchronisation issues.

"Locking" the map, you probably want to avoid if necessary. You'd need keep strong references to all the data (and evict if not null). That is going to be ugly.

Comment: For locking, I was thinking I could simply copy the whole thing into a normal HashMap

Comment: Well, you can copy the contents of the map, but then you have to dereference the soft references as well. Although copying instead of locking is a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using something like [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/features.html) instead of re-inventing a caching system. It's super simple to use, very configurable, and works great.

Answer (score 0):

As matt b said, something like Ehcache or JbossCache is a good first step.

If you want something light-weight and in-process, look at google collections.  For example, you can use MapMaker (http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) to make a map with Soft/Weak keys and values, so it would cache only those items it has room for (though you wouldn't get LRU).

Comment: Oops - better link: http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need in the past and this is how I implemented my cache:

- there is a cache memory manager, which has a minimum and a maximum memory limit(max limit it matters anyway)
- every registered cache has the following(important) parameters: maximum capacity(most of the time you have a higher limit, you don't want go hold more than X items) & percent memory usage
- I use a LinkedHashMap and a ReentrantReadWriteLock to guard the cache.
- every X puts I calculate the mean memory consumption per entry and trigger eviction(async) if the calculated memory limit > allowed memory limit.
- of course memory computation doesn't actually shows the real memory consumption but comparing the computed memory with the real value(using a profiler) I find that it is close enough.

I was planning to put also an additional guard on the cache, to evict in case puts are going faster than memory based evictions, but until now I didn't find the need to do it.