# What is the best way to cache and reuse immutable singleton objects in Java?

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, reusability, static-factory

I have a class representing a set of values that will be used as a key in maps.

This class is immutable and I want to make it a singleton for every distinct set of values, using the static factory pattern.
The goal is to prevent identical objects from being created many (100+) times and to optimize the equals method.

I am looking for the best way to cache and reuse previous instances of this class.
The first thing that pops to mind is a simple hashmap, but are there alternatives?

Comment: So those singletons are used as keys in maps? Now you want to make a map to store the keys that you use in other maps? What keys are you going to use to lookup the singletons from the map? Isn't this going in a wrong direction - you first need to lookup a key in a map to be able to use that key to lookup something in another map?

Comment: So just what is your caching policy? You want to cache all instances ever created, forever and ever? How many different instances can there be?

Comment: @Jesper The singleton contains different fields. It's much easier to work with keys that are single objects. So what I want to do is find the key that is composed of a given set of parameters, or make a new one if no such key exists. Then I can use that single object as a key in a map, which is likely to be faster and cleaner than using a nested map for every sub-key

@polygenelubricants They have to be kept for as long as other parts of the application have references to them.

Comment: for your cache, you may want to have a map that has soft values then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two situations:

- If the number of distinct objects is small and fixed, you should use an `enum`

  - They're not instantiatiable beyond the declared constants, and [`EnumMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is optimized for it
- Otherwise, you can cache immutable instances as you planned:

  - If the values are indexable by numbers in a contiguous range, then an array can be used

    - This is how e.g. [`Integer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) cache instances  in a given range for `valueOf`
  - Otherwise you can use some sort of [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Depending on the usage pattern, you may choose to only cache, say, the last *N* instances, instead of all instances created so far. This is the approach used in e.g. [`re.compile`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile) in Python's regular expression module. If *N* is small enough (e.g. 5), then a simple array with a linear search may also work just fine.

For `Map` based solution, perhaps a useful implementation is [`java.util.LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which allows you to enforce LRU-like policies if you `@Override` the [`removeEldestEntry`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29).

There is also [`LRUMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap.html) from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections) that implement this policy more directly.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/`enums`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 1: Consider static factory methods instead of constructors*
- [Wikipedia/Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

#### Related questions

- [Easy, simple to use LRU cache in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224868/easy-simple-to-use-lru-cache-in-java)
- [LRU LinkedHashMap that limits size based on available memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646257/lru-linkedhashmap-that-limits-size-based-on-available-memory)

  - Guava `MapMaker`, soft keys and values, etc
- [How would you implement an LRU cache in Java 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221525/how-would-you-implement-an-lru-cache-in-java-6)

Comment: To be clear, `Integer#valueOf(int)` cache is [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), not Object pool pattern (the difference is: instances in an object pool are droppable/releasable).

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to make sounds like an example of the [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), so looking for references to that might help clarify your thinking.

Storing them in a map of some sort is indeed a common implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What do your objects look like? If your objects are fairly simple I think you should consider not caching them - object creation is usually quite fast. I think you should evaluate whether the possibly small performance boost is worth the added complexity and effort of a cache.