# Java Collection implementaiton with timeout of the elements

Tags: java, collections

Is there some collection implementation supporting expiration of the elements.

For example:

```
Collection<User> cachedUsers = new ExpirableList<User>(10000);
```

where

```
public ExpirableList(final long timeout){...}
```

And after given time (`10000ms` in this particular example), added elements will be removed from the collection. By using this, we will prevent overflow of our `cachedUsers` collection.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for... a cache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352864

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Guava supports a cache with timed expiration. See [Guava Explained's page on caches](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained).

An alternative is an LRU (least-recently used) cache that disposes of the oldest accessed element when a new element is inserted.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear how you're trying to use the collection, but Guava's [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) may help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement this by writing a wrapper for, say, a `TreeMap` where you let the insertion time be the key. On each insert, you could drop the head list which has "timed out".

Using insertion time as an indication on whether or not in should be dropped seems like a bad idea though. It seems better to go with some LRU (least recently used) cache for instance. Such caches are readily available in libraries such as [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) for instance. **Don't reinvent the wheel.**

**Related questions:**

- [How would you implement an LRU cache in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221525/how-would-you-implement-an-lru-cache-in-java-6)
- [LRU LinkedHashMap that limits size based on available memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646257/lru-linkedhashmap-that-limits-size-based-on-available-memory)
- [Easy, simple to use LRU cache in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224868/easy-simple-to-use-lru-cache-in-java)

Comment: Insertions committed at the same time are very rare, ain't they?

Comment: Haha. Good point. Solution is obviously to let each timestamp map to a set of objects :-)